# how to trouble shoot when failed to run stored procedure in oracle sql developer?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle-sqldeveloper

I ran a stored procedure in oracle sql developer, and got following message

```
Connecting to the database QAV41PRODO.
Process exited.
Disconnecting from the database QAV41PRODO
```

when I debug it, I get the following messages:

```
*Connecting to the database SAMPLEDB.
Executing PL/SQL: ALTER SESSION SET PLSQL_DEBUG=TRUE
Executing PL/SQL: CALL DBMS_DEBUG_JDWP.CONNECT_TCP( '111.111.111.111', '11111' )
Debugger accepted connection from database on port 11111.
Source breakpoint: EMP_SEL.pls:1
Source breakpoint: EMP_SEL.pls:5
Source breakpoint: EMP_SEL.pls:6
Executing PL/SQL: CALL DBMS_DEBUG_JDWP.DISCONNECT()
Process exited.
Disconnecting from the database QAV41PRODO.
Debugger disconnected from database.*
```

the stored procedure I am trying to run is as follows:

```
    create or replace PROCEDURE EMP_SEL
(empID varchar2,
 cur_out OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
AS
BEGIN
        OPEN cur_out FOR
      SELECT   *  FROM EMP_TABLE
        WHERE EMPID = 'empID'
        ORDER BY EMPID;
END;
```

so, what would be the reason that I am not getting any result from this. 
the select statement works fine and get me the results.

your help will be appreciated, 
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: are you sure the procedure isn't being executed? have you tried 'catching' the cur_out refcursor? it won't just show up w/o you writing some code - are you on 12c? of the db? https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/implicit-statement-results-12cr1

Comment: Replace this snippet `WHERE EMPID = 'empID'` with this one: `WHERE EMPID = empID` - just remove apostrophes around `empId`.

Comment: @krokodilko `WHERE EMPID = 'empID'` appears to be an attempt to restrict the result set to the passed parameter. Removing the quotes will create a namespace collision, effectively `where 1=1`. The OP needs to give the parameter a different name to the column to avoid this e.g. `p_empid`.

Comment: It is compiled successfully, but when I execute it, I didn't get any result out of it.

Comment: @tman how exactly are you executing it and where are you looking for the results? if you use the code editor's 'execute' button, there will be an output panel in the log panel at the bottom with your refcursor(s)

Comment: @thatjeffsmith that's where I look for the result in oracle sql developer, but didn't get anything. Though the select query itself returning the results.

Comment: please show the anonymous block you are running to execute the procedure - what you see when you hit the execute button

Answer (score 0):

> what would be the reason that I am not getting any result from this. the select statement works fine and get me the results.

I think the problem is `WHERE EMPID = 'empID'` appears to be an attempt to restrict the result set to the passed parameter but you are in fact comparing the EMPID to the string `'empID'`. That will probably return no matches.

Removing the quotes will create a namespace collision, effectively `where 1=1`, because SQL is not case sensitive and `EMPID` is the same as `empID`. So you need to give the parameter a different name to the column to avoid this e.g. `p_empid`.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE EMP_SEL
    (p_empID varchar2,
     cur_out OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)

AS
BEGIN
    OPEN cur_out FOR
       SELECT   *  FROM EMP_TABLE
        WHERE EMPID = p_empID
        ORDER BY EMPID;
END;
```

Comment: As suggested, I have replaced empID with other name and it still didn't give me any result

Comment: We've done the best we can with what information you have given us. We only know what you tell it us. You need to post a reproducible test case: give us some sample data and expected outcome derived from that input, show you call this procedure and show how you test what results you get.

Answer (score 0):

After removing quotes from `'empID'`, I try to compile and sql developer was hanged, that was another issue. 
Then I found and killed the session for compiling the Stored Procedure,and compiled again applied the changes and it was successfully compiled.

Thanks for all your help...